# Does operand order make any difference when evaluating equality or identity in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, equality

Question: *does operand order make any difference when evaluating equality or identity in JavaScript?*

In code, is `(0 == value)` faster or more correct than `(value == 0)`? (Note that this question is equally valid for the identity operator, `===`.)

Since both the equality and identity operators are commutative, I don't believe the operand order  should make a difference in evaluation performance, unless there's some inherent benefit to the left-side literal in the computation of the equality algorithm itself. The only reason I wonder is that I recently used Google's [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/) to boil down some JavaScript, and noticed that

`if (array.length == 0 && typeof length === 'number') {`

had been compiled to

`if(0 == b.length && "number" === typeof c) {`.

In both equality expressions—one loose and one strict—Closure has reversed the order of my operands, placing a Number literal and a String literal on the left–hand sides of their respective expressions.

This made me curious.

I read through the *Equality Operators* section of the [ECMAScript 5.1 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (section 11.9, pp. 80–82) and found that while the equality algorithms start by examining the left–hand operands first, there's no indication that it's faster or better to use a literal as that operand.

Is there something about ECMAScript's type–checking that makes examination of literals optimal? Could it be some optimization quirk in the Closure compiler? Or perhaps an implementation detail in an older version of ECMAScript's equality algorithm which has been nullified in this newer version of the spec?

Comment: I think this "error" comes as a side effect of how google parsers and rebuilds your code and has nothing to do with side effects or correct ness of operand order

Comment: To check the speed, simply run tests at [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com). This will, of course, only measure the browsers you have available running the test-cases you create, rather than offering a theoretical/'objective' assessment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsperf.com/lr-equality

I can't really give you an explanation, but you can check the numbers. They seem to be equal (now).

Comment: hello, I have an interesting theory about the `greater/less than` operators. It could be interesting if you could add those too. e.g `a < 5 and 5 > a`

Comment: The numbers are incomparable, though, so just look at the raw data: http://jsperf.com/lr-equality

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. I've run performance tests too, but wondered if there's an algorithmic reason for the difference because that might indicate some larger trend in JavaScript performance. Essentially, I'm trying to determine if there's a source reason for the performance difference and whether I can obtain other performance benefits by changing a habit. But I appreciate the input!

Answer (score 2):

A lot of time people code with the variable on the right as a style convention. Main reason it can catch errors with sloppy coding.

The following code is most likely a bug, but the if statement will evaluate to true.

```
if( n = 1 ) { }
```

and this will throw an error

```
if( 1 = n ) { }
```

Comment: @PiersMainwaring He didn't say it evaluates to true *because* of a bug--he said that when it's written it usually *is* a bug, and a comparison was intended (as opposed to an assignment). He's answering your question: it's not a performance thing, it's a way of reducing one class of errors.

Comment: @DaveNewton Ah, understood. I was focused on the equality issue and misread the answer. My apologies.

Comment: So, you're implying Closure Compiler might be intended to be some kind of QA tool, too?